# Upgrading WCF project and implement security

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I was assigned with a mission to upgrade a legacy WCF and angular project written long time ago by a freelancer and add authentication and authorization to it.
I am quite new to the project and I was quite horrified when I saw the code.

Unfortunately, I can't share code, but I can tell you that:

1. Client-side is an SPA angularjs application.
2. Project is quite small.
3. There is no ORM - Only SQL (Stored procedure) queries.
4. The database is SQL Server.
5. The database Users, Roles etc.. schema was decided by the freelancer and was not built by any tool (like Microsoft Membership)
   and without any regard to any conventional user table schemas. User table has a username, email, password, and a lot of other application data columns.
6. Most of the database table columns are encrypted/decrypted by the server before writing or read to/from the database. He wrote an encryption service.
7. Password was encrypted with a symmetric encryption (and only once).
8. Data being sent to the server is encrypted by the client and decrypted by the server and vis verse. The server always receives and return
   strings (I guess he didn't trust HTTPS). 
   There are 2 encryptions - one between client and server and the other one between server and database.
9. The server always returns status 200, even when there is a failure. The return type must always be an object of type {success, resultObj} - this is what the client expected.
10. This system works on production with live users so changing schema will force schema change in production as well.
11. WCF server only serves site requests for now but might be needed to serve other application as well in the near future
12. Fortunately, the business logic is well organized in services and there is no code in the WCF controllers except calling services functions.
13. There is a separate project for the WCF service and another one for the angularjs application
14. There is no authorization or authentication at all!!! Login doesn't do anything (no cookie, no session, no token- no nothing).

Requirements:

1. I need to implement a bear minimum of authentication and authorization.
2. I need to update the server technology as much as we can to help us build new features on top of it in the near future.
3. Time is at the essence

I know it a lot to process and I am willing to share all data necessary (except code).
I read a lot about Asp.Net Identity and Identity Server and Web API Security and MVC Security but I really don't know which way to go.

Questions:

1. I am thinking of killing the WCF Service project and opening a new project where I will move all my business logic too.
   I'm not sure If I need to create an MVC or Web API application. My client is angularjs spa application. If I don't need razor views should I use Web API?
2. Can I implement Identity Server on a database with a custom-made schema without entity framework? Is it recommended?
3. I understood that Identity Server is not used to authenticate and authorize the request, if so, what should I use on top of it?

If you have any thoughts, specific articles or any guiding questions, I will really really appreciate some help.